# Fill In UIView With Multiple Colors iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, cgrect

I'd like to fill in a UIView Background with multiple colors.  I want to use it as a status bar of sorts, so if 1/2 the necessary steps are completed, the UIView Background will be 1/2 green and 1/2 red.  When the user completes more steps (say 2/3), more of the UIView Background turns green (2/3 in this case).

I'm guessing I need to override

```
-(void) drawREct: (CGRect) rect
```

I imagine I would get the UIView, figure out how big it is, and divide it into 2 rectangles and then fill in those rectangles.

Another option would be to add 2 UIViews programmatically, but I'm a fan of IB.

Is it possible to divy up a UIView like I want?

Thanks

Comment: is there any kind of transition between red and green?

Comment: @Nick Weaver - I wasn't planning on any transition.  My thought was just to have the red and green butt up against each other.  Would a transition make a difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an IB solution, but you can subclass UIView and override the `drawRect` method to add a custom gradient. This will allow you to put any number of colors you like and have them transition hard or smoothly. There are many nice tutorials online that should different ways to do this (some more elaborate, some quite simple).

Another option that is fairly simple, is to override `drawRect`, make the background red, then `fill` a rectangle that takes up the bottom half of the view. It doesn't allow for fancy or smooth transitions between colors, but it's very easy to implement. For instance, something along these lines should work:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect upperRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height * percentDone);
    CGRect lowerRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height * percentDone), rect.size.width, rect.size.height *(1-percentDone));

    [[UIColor redColor] set]; 
    UIRectFill(upperRect);
    [[UIColor greenColor] set]; 
    UIRectFill(lowerRect);
}
```

Here `percentDone` is a float (declare, `property(nonatomic)`, `synthesize`) that you can tie to the user's steps. Then just update the view when the user does something by

```
splitView.percentDone = .5;
[splitView setNeedsDisplay];
```

You can smooth this out with animations as well.

Comment: @Peng- Awesome.  This is exactly what I was looking to do.  I can still use IB to define rect, then I just hook this up in code.  Thanks!

Comment: Is that supposed to be `(rec.size.width * percentDone)` or should it be `(rect.size.height * percentDone)`?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to set the background color for your background view to, say, red. Then add another view to that background view and call that the indicator view. Size and position the indicator view to cover the background, and set its background color to green. Connect the indicator view to an outlet in your view controller, and have the view controller adjust its width (or height) as necessary to correspond with the progress of the task at hand.

Another way would be as @PengOne suggests: create a custom view, give it a 'progress' property, and override -drawRect: to draw the contents appropriately. If you're going this route, there's nothing to stop you from getting a little creative. Instead of just filling two rectangles, make the boundary between the two colors a little more interesting. You could add ripples or bubbles that, with an appropriate sound effect, might look like a container filling with liquid. Or you could do a [Qix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEq-mxFDuHM)-like animation that slowly fills the screen... ;-)